# How to get main url of project in reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am working with reactjs and i want to get fullpath/hostname/baseurl of my project (inside component file),How can i do this ?I tried with following code,but not working,giving me following error

```
"Unexpected token `{`. Expected * for generator"
```

I tried with following code

```
import absoluteUrl from 'next-absolute-url';
class Header extends Component {
const { origin } = absoluteUrl(req)
const apiURL = ${origin}
render() 
    {
        ...//my code
    }   
}
```

Comment: You've just got a syntax error (missing \` after `${origin}`. You can more simply use `const apiURL = origin;`, there's no need to use a template literal around a single variable

Comment: @Phil: no you are wrong,still giving me error

Comment: I'm wrong that you have a syntax error? I don't think so. Even the error message says you do and they don't tend to be wrong. FYI, you still have one after your edit

Comment: @Phil: kindly update my code so i can check

Comment: I already showed you... `const apiURL = origin;`

Comment: @Phil "const" giving me error

Comment: Calling `absoluteUrl(req)` won't work inside a React component as you don't have a `req` object to pass to it. You can simply use `window.location.host` instead, or call `absoluteUrl()` without `req` if you absolutely want to use that.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the window object.

Note: when using window, do wrap it inside the below if condition, else it will error out when you're using SSR.

```
import '../styles/globals.css';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  let fullPath = '';
  if (typeof window !== undefined) {
    fullPath = window.location.hostname;
  }
  console.log(fullPath);
  return <Component {...pageProps} className={fullPath === 'insert your path here' ? 'insert class to apply if true' : 'insert class to apply if false'}/>;
}

export default MyApp;
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-xfqc2p?file=pages%2F_app.js)

Comment: i am new in reactjs, kindly tell me how can i use with class component ?( in my code )

Comment: i am using "class component" not "functional component"

Comment: @sky same principles! just this code inside render!

Answer (score 0):

So firstly, remember your code runs on client and server so any access to window needs to be wrapped in a check.

```
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    var path = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/someting'; // (or whatever)
  } else {
    // work out what you want to do server-side...
  }
```

Comment: This answer does not contribute anything new to the topic. Please check the other answers to see if your answer offers any new information before posting.